# How to Prevent Ubuntu (running in VMware) shutt down when the PC is shut down accidentally?

Tags: vmware

I'm using Ubuntu in VMware 8 in a public lab and sometimes the computer may be restarted or shut down accidentally. Is there any way to prevent ubuntu from shutting down in order to continue running the program from where it has been stopped?

Comment: What do you mean by, prevent Ubuntu from shutting down? When the lab pc restarted or shuts down, everything shuts down??? I've got a feeling that you are taking about saving a session?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the host operating system shuts down *uncontrolled* (you say accidentally) be it by an unwanted manual shut down, after an application crash, or worst a power failure, there is **no way** any guest operating system (not even Ubuntu) can detect and react on such an incident. All data from the guest OS will be lost.

To prevent this we need to at least save the guest session prior to shut down of the host. Depending on the host OS it may be done automatically by including this into the shutdown routine (which of course needs time to finish *before* the host machine was powered off).

Comment: thanks, yes I mean how to save the session. dear Takkat can you please guide me how to include that into shutdown routine? thank you

Comment: You need VMWare's [Suspend and Resume](http://www.vmware.com/support/ws5/doc/ws_preserve_suspend_resume.html) feature. This is run from the **host OS**. Sorry, but we have no experience on how to do that from commnand line or script.

Comment: On Windows 7 applications can prevent shutdown. If his host is Win7, he could write a service, that prevents shutdown.